# Reading BASE64 from HttpURLConnection's InputStream in Java 8

Tags: rest, java-8, base64

I am facing issues in reading a BASE64 response which has content type "Application/pdf". I have a java class as a middleware (packaged as jar) between IBM BAW and REST Api. Java class receives the POST request contents (JSON) from IBM BAW which it uses to make a POST request to REST api. And sends back the Api response to IBM BAW, in exact same format as it is received. Issue here is, I am just able to read partial response and not the entire response. Api response (Base64 encode)is contained in svcConn's InputStream. Can anyone help me figure what's wrong with the code and how do I retrieve the response in InputStream and send it back.
I am aware of the BASE64 class in Java.util package but not exactly sure of how I can use it for the large inputStream. Really appreciate your inputs. Below is my code, please note, I am restricted to use java8.

```
    private static String sendRequestToService() {
    String jsonStr =  getJsonStraing(); //returns JSON for POST request
    HttpURLConnection svcConn = null;
    StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
            svcConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            svcConn.setDoOutput(true);
            svcConn.setDoInput(true);
            svcConn.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic auth here");
            svcConn.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            svcConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(jsonStr.length()));
            svcConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            svcConn.setRequestMethod("POST");   
            svcConn.connect();
            OutputStream os = svcConn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    
            writer1.write(jsonStr);
            writer1.flush();
            writer1.close();
            
            int responseCode = svcConn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                InputStream inputStream = svcConn.getInputStream();
                textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                  (inputStream))) {
                    String str = null;
                    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        textBuilder.append(str);
                    }
                }
                
            } 

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    finally {}
    return textBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: application/pdf is a binary format, so you can't cleanly put its raw data in an UTF-8 string

Comment: Thank you @Evert and @K J. The api provider is encoding byte array to Base64 and sending it in Response. If it was the byte array in response, I think then there will be no issue? I am not sure why they chose to encode response to Base64. 
Is there any third party lib that can be used for this? Wanted to avoid it but I may be running out of options I feel.

Comment: @user1902124 the problem with your question is that what you're asking is not really possible or logical. You're asking to turn the PDF into a string. You should not do this. Update your question to state your actual goal? Anything that can be done with libraries in Java can be done without libraries in Java. Libraries are written in Java, so you just need to write more java.

Comment: @Evert, thanks. I just updated the post to explain what I am trying to do. Please see "Update" at the end of post.

Comment: @user1902124, the update looks good. You can probably rephrase that as: "i'm trying to decode the base64 PDF, and then re-submit that to a REST api in the request body". I don't have the answer to this (not a java dev), but updating your question to make that the main focus is likely going to get better/faster responses from the people that do

Comment: @K J , good catch I just updated the code snippet to remove "UTF-8"

Comment: It doesn’t matter which encoding you use; the fundamental problem of your method is that it returns a `String` for what is supposed to be a PDF. We can’t solve your problem when the requirements are broken. Besides that, you should fix your error handling.